# React Native run android Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native

I try this command on Mac terminal

```
  react-native run-android
```

and got this error

```
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * Where:
    Build file '/Users/web2/AwesomeProject/android/app/build.gradle' line: 1

   * What went wrong:
   A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
```

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

```
  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  BUILD FAILED
```

I have installed

```
  java version "1.6.0_65"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error by updating Java version 1.6 to 1.8 :)